# Webcam on Skype and Teamviewer

Tags: skype, webcam, teamviewer, preload

I use a Trust webcam on my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. It used to work fine until, for other reasons, I decided to reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 one month ago. Now I can't use it with Skype or Teamviewer, although it works with Cheese.
It previously needed a v4l2 preload script to work with Skype, but now it doesn't seem to work anymore.
How can I fix it?